# How to assign ipv6 IP addresses to net devices?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

The following is a series of command to setup two network namespaces and a router in between. I wanted to connect the two to try things out.

This works as you can see below using ipv4, how can I assign ipv6 addresses to the net devices and test it out?

```
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip netns add enasource
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip netns add enadestination
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip netns add Router100
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip link add veth1-ns type veth peer name veth1-rt
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip link add veth2-ns type veth peer name veth2-rt
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip link set veth1-ns netns enasource
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip link set veth2-ns netns enadestination
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip link set veth1-rt netns Router100
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip link set veth2-rt netns Router100
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip netns exec enasource bash
root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig -a
lo: flags=8<LOOPBACK>  mtu 65536
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth1-ns: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether fe:c7:0f:42:e9:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig lo up
root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig veth1-ns 1.1.1.2/24 up
root@n62-006-049:~# exit
exit
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip netns exec enadestination bash
root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig lo up
root@n62-006-049:~# iconfig veth2-ns 2.2.2.2/24 
bash: iconfig: command not found
root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig veth2-ns 2.2.2.2/24 up
root@n62-006-049:~# exit
exit
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip netns exec Router100 bash
root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig -a
lo: flags=8<LOOPBACK>  mtu 65536
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth1-rt: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:cd:e4:82:0e:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth2-rt: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ba:a8:6f:a8:c8:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig lo up
root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig veth1-rt 1.1.1.1/24 up
root@n62-006-049:~# ifconfig veth2-rt 2.2.2.1/24 up
root@n62-006-049:~# ping 1.1.1.2
PING 1.1.1.2 (1.1.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.004 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.005 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.003 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3061ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.003/0.011/0.033/0.012 ms
root@n62-006-049:~# ping 2.2.2.2 
PING 2.2.2.2 (2.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 2.2.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from 2.2.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.007 ms
64 bytes from 2.2.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.004 ms
^C
--- 2.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2066ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.004/0.013/0.029/0.011 ms
root@n62-006-049:~# exit
exit
root@cache09.fra4:~# ip netns exec enasource bash
root@n62-006-049:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
1.1.1.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 veth1-ns
root@n62-006-049:~# ping 2.2.2.1
connect: Network is unreachable
root@n62-006-049:~# route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 1.1.1.1
root@n62-006-049:~# ping 2.2.2.1
PING 2.2.2.1 (2.2.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 2.2.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.015 ms
64 bytes from 2.2.2.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 2.2.2.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.004 ms
64 bytes from 2.2.2.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.003 ms
64 bytes from 2.2.2.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
^C
--- 2.2.2.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4099ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.003/0.006/0.015/0.005 ms
root@n62-006-049:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way as one normally assigns IPv4 addresses – using `ip address add`:

```
ip link set veth2-ns up
ip addr add 2.2.2.2/24 dev veth2-ns
ip addr add 2001:db8::2/64 dev veth2-ns
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 2.2.2.1
ip route add ::/0 via 2001:db8::1
```

Comment: can you please post the complete setup? I am a total noob to ipv6.